# How do cessationists explain 1 Corinthians 1:7?

Tags: 1-corinthians, paul-apostle, spiritual-gifts, cessationism, continuationism

> "Therefore you do not lack any spiritual gift as you eagerly await the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ"- 1 Corinthians 1:7

I'm neutral in the cessationism vs continuationism debate but the above verse does seem to imply that spiritual gifts would continue until Jesus comes back.

Comment: I think it means exactly what it says - Spiritual gifts must always be available to the church else it could not function!  How could the church function without administration, helps, teachers, preaching, etc.  In my observation, the cessationist doctrine evolved to avoid the embarrassment of the conspicuous absence of gifts in some quarters of the church.

Comment: As far as I understand, cessationists do not believe all spiritual gifts have ceased, only the "sign gifts" such as tongues and prophecy. Other gifts, such as the gift of teaching, continue. I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't have any Bible references to back this up right now and don't have time to find some, but as far as I know, this is the belief held by most cessationists, myself included.

Comment: There is a story (certainly apocryphal) that says that when St Augustine of Hippo entered a room where the pope sat in front of table piled with money, the pope said to Augustine, "You see that the church can no longer say 'silver and gold have I none!'"  To this Augustine replied, "but neither can she say, 'stand up and walk'".

Comment: @Someone - such a doctrine is called, "partial cessationism" which contains fatal flaws - (1) How can men decide which gifts the Holy Spirit distributes? (2) Why are some gifts miraculous and some are not?  Surely, by definition, all the Holy Spirit's gifts are miraculous?

Comment: See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/69081/is-pauls-singling-out-of-3-specific-spiritual-gifts-prophecies-tongues-knowl/69084#69084  and  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/68839/can-ephesians-220-be-used-as-to-prove-the-cessation-of-the-offices-of-apostle-a/68858#68858 and  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/can-1-cor-138-10-be-used-as-to-prove-that-radical-continuationism-is-necessaril/66555#66555

Comment: @Dottard I think https://www.gotquestions.org/sign-gifts.html gives a good explanation of why some gifts have ceased and some have not. Basically, some gifts are no longer needed, so they have ceased, at least as everyday occurrences. If there was a trustworthy report of e.g. a missionary miraculously preaching the Gospel in a language he had never learned, I would not doubt that this was a spiritual gift at all, but I do believe that the gift of tongues (along with the other sign gifts) are no longer needed on a regular basis.

Comment: @Someone - fair enough but I must beg to differ - I have far too many stories of miraculous things that have happened, repeatedly to some to even entertain such an idea.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who leans towards cessationism, I might still find a continuationist argument compelling if Paul had said something like:

> "Therefore **no believer** will lack any spiritual gift as **they** eagerly await the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ"- 1 Corinthians 1:7

But since he actually wrote to the Corinthians:

> "Therefore **you** do not lack any spiritual gift as **you** eagerly await the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ"- 1 Corinthians 1:7

I simply interpret Paul to be accurately describing the specific circumstances of the Corinthians as a group existing at that time and wouldn't expect this statement to broadly describe all Christians in every time period.

Comment: What would revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ entail for those Corinthians? Is this referring to how they'd see Jesus after they pop?

Answer (score 1):

The Revelation of Jesus Christ is always spoken of as a future prophecy, since the Apostles didn’t know the day and hour themselves and were still instructed to write it down due to the Holy Spirit’s instruction. (2 Peter 1:20-21).

The gifts that the Spirit distributes are according to His will:

> God also bearing witness both with signs and wonders, with various
> miracles, and gifts of the Holy Spirit, according to His own will?
> **Hebrews 2:4**
>
> “There are diversities of gifts, but the same Spirit. There are
> differences of ministries, but the same Lord. And there are
> diversities of activities, but it is the same God who works all in
> all.
>
> But the manifestation of the Spirit is given to each one for the
> profit of all: for to one is given the word of wisdom through the
> Spirit, to another the word of knowledge through the same Spirit,
>
> to another faith by the same Spirit, to another gifts of healings by
> the same Spirit, to another the working of miracles, to another
> prophecy, to another discerning of spirits, to another different kinds
> of tongues, to another the interpretation of tongues.
>
> But one and the same Spirit works all these things, distributing to
> each one individually as He wills.” **1 Corinthians 12:4-11**

We have to also take into the historical context to which Paul is writing, even about tongues.  Does Paul indicate some are given tongues?  Yes.  Does Paul also within his inspired literature mention tongues will cease?  Yes.

> “Love never fails. But whether there are prophecies, they will fail;
> ***whether there are tongues, they will cease***; whether there is knowledge, it will vanish away. For we know in part and we prophesy in
> part. But when that which is perfect has come, then that which is in
> part will be done away.” **1 Corinthians 13:8-10**

It’s therefore likely that when the “***perfect has come***” that Paul is referencing the close of the canon of scripture instead of the argument of the Second coming of Christ being that reference.

**Conclusion**:

It’s likely that 1 Cor 1:7 speaks of a future tense reality of Christ’s return, and that believers in Corinth will not lack any spiritual gift according to the will of God through His Spirit, who has control over how long tongues will last in this age.

*There is no conflict or contradiction when assuming the Historical Context of this reality.*

Answer (score 0):

In looking  at the context of this verse it shows that each of them have been already given everything they need in Christ Jesus.  They have been given the grace of God, they have been in enriched in Christ Jesus ( who is their life)  They were  made rich  in Him, with Everything. They do not need anything more.  The Lord will bring them all the way through, to the end… After all he is a Savior who saves to the end.

Perhaps they were being told they needed more by some others.

> 4I give thanks to my God always concerning you for the grace of God that was given to you in Christ Jesus, 5that in everything you were enriched in Him, in all discourse and all knowledge, 6according as the testimony of the Christ was confirmed in you, 7so that you are not behind in any gift, waiting for the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ, 8who also will confirm you to the end—unblamable in the day of our Lord Jesus Christ; 9faithful [is] God, through whom you were called into the fellowship of His Son Jesus Christ our Lord.

Answer (score 0):

When you take the first audience perspective into consideration, and understand that "soon" did not mean 2,000 + years and counting, then the answer to your question is Yes.  The spiritual gifts were promised to that generation of the 1st century AD as Peter stated on the day of Pentecost.

> *"38 and Peter said unto them, `Reform, and be baptized each of you on the name of Jesus Christ, to remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Spirit, 39 for to you is the promise, and to your children, and to all those afar off, as many as the Lord our God shall call.'"* (Acts 2:38-39, YLT)

The promise was to those of that generation... "to you and to your children".. those standing there at the temple in Jerusalem in 30 or 31 AD.  "And to all those afar off..." were the gentiles who had not yet been grafted in, but still of that generation.

So, Paul's statement to those of Corinth just before the passover of 55 AD (1) were of that same generation that rec'd the promise of Joel's prophesy on the day of Pentecost about 24 years earlier, and were still looking forward to Jesus' coming in judgment of that same generation.

> *"Verily I say to you, this generation may not pass away till all these may come to pass."*  (Matt. 24:34, YLT)

It was their generation that was going to see His return, His second appearance to them (Heb. 9:28).  It is not our generation; it is not "this generation" today when we are reading.  It was "this generation" almost 2,000 years ago.  Their generation was going to see the revelation of Jesus Christ (Yeshua) in the promised judgments which He told His disciples in the venacular they would recognize.

> *"And concerning that day and the hour no one hath known..."*  (Matt. 24:36, YLT).

The very words they associated with the Feast of Trumpets (Yom Teruah) on the first of Tishri. Can you really believe that Jesus did not know when He was going to return?  He didn't tell his disciples which year and which 1st of Tishri, but if they had been following the pattern from the OT, they might have expected the mirror of the 40 years wandering in the wilderness to be repeated for the probate of the gospel of Christ throughout the "world" of the ancient Roman empire - the 4th beast kingdom from Daniel's prophesies.

Because that is when Daniel was told that judgment would sit (Dan. 7:23-27).  Christ told them that when that temple fell that He would separate out all those from Hades with the sheep (righteous) to his right, and the goats (wicked rebellious ones) to his left (Matt. 25:31-46).  As Matt. 25 was linked to the prophesy of the fall of the temple in Matt. 24, and as that temple did fall under the Romans in AD 70, then Jesus carried out that judgment in AD 70.

And, the spiritual gifts which were dispensed by the laying on of the hands of the apostles (Acts 19:1-6) were the miraculous proofs to the people that the gospel was truly authorized by and sent by God, then those died out just as Paul told them they would (1 Cor. 13:8-13) when that which was perfect was come.

That which was perfect has meaning for the righteous one, our Savior, and for His kingdom; both of which came in judgment at the fall of that temple in AD 70 and with the full completed establishment of His perfect everlasting kingdom at the completion of the old Mosaic sacrificial covenant.

Jesus did it all.  He kept His word to His disciples and we can rely upon it.  We have the record of those miraculous deeds, and we have the word of the Holy Spirit.  We have the Spirit through His word.  All we have to do is study it.

The miraculous gifts were promised for that generation and were very public demonstrations for the people to be able to believe in Him.

Note:

1. [Date of 1 & 2 Corinthians](http://datingthenewtestament.com/Corinthians.htm)

Other readings:

It's Not The End of the World - Part VIII: Confirmation From Acts 2 [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/24/its-not-the-end-of-the-world-part-viii-confirmation-from-acts-2/)

The Signs of Revelation  Part I: The Time of His Coming [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/02/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-i-the-time-of-his-coming/)